# image border is larger than image height bigcartel css html

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, border

I have created a website using `bigcartel` and I am currently struggling with some of the images.

You can see on the [page](http://www.murkyapparel.com/) that the image in the main content area does not fill the border completely. There are a couple of pixels missing at the bottom. I have not long been using bigcartel and so it may be due to my misunderstanding their existing formatting.

Feel free to ask for more info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As always, the easiest way to debug your code and to be more likely to get answer here is to provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your code. Isolate only the relevant part, and add all dependencies (front-end frameworks, ...) to make it workable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll make my question clearer next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block` for the `img` tag.

```
.product_tile img {
 display:block
}
```